# Adding another row programmatically

Tags: oracle-adf

[image]

[image]

How can we add another row when we click the `Add new RFQ details` button?

Answer (score 1):

.. to be more precise: What Shay means is that you drag and drop the CreateInsert operation from the data control panel for the ViewObject that populates the table in your screen shot. This creates a method binding and automatically references it from the command button action listener property

Answer (score 0):

You invoke the createInsert operation of the VO into which you want to add a row.

Comment: But i want to add row by programatically because here unitprice,status are given by my values not from VO and also all components are coming from Different VO's. simly my requerment is i want to add another row  when we clicking button.